# Can't get Fuseki2 to work on Ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, jena, fuseki

Not able to do anything when I visit the server's IP at port 3030, when I start fuseki2 on my localhost it seems to work fine, I'm able to add datasets, modify, etc. but I start it on a Google Compute Engine instance (Ubuntu 14.04) it starts but the GUI doesn't allow me to do anything.What am I doing wrong here ? I've managed to get fuseki1 running on the server successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default configuration is to restrict access to the admin UI operations to "localhost".  See the comments in file shiro.ini for how to change this.

Comment: Outcomment like `#/$/** = localhostFilter`.